# Searching in database for entire string / phrase

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I have a form where there are **two radio buttons**.

**One should search for entire string** and **second one for at least one word** from string.

For example:

I will search for "***Awesome ideas for startup***".

If I check "Search for entire string / phrase", where it must contain exactly what I typed.

- I want return something like "There where many ***awesome ideas for startup***".
- Or "***Awesome ideas for startup*** that will blow your mind".

If I check "Search for all words contained".

- I want return something like "This ***startup*** is amazing".

I don't have problem with submitting the form or anything like that, but problem with SQL query that will return results which I mentioned above.

```
if ($_POST['selectedRadio'] == 'entireString') { 
   $query = '/* QUERY HERE */';
} elseif($_POST['selectedRadio'] == 'containedWords') {
   $query = '/* QUERY HERE */';
}
```

Is there any efficient and fast way to get those wished results?

Thanks.

Comment: Searching the entire database metadata ? or real table data ?

Comment: Real table data, but I already solved this. Thanks for posting anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE %your_string%
```

This code will search in table exactly what you're looking for, string or phrase. Google for sql like command and build query what you need.

Comment: I needed to separate fulltext searching and exact match in string. I already managed it, but thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Already solved this problem.

"This startup is amazing". - Managed to return this with Fulltext search.

"There where many awesome ideas for startup". - Managed to return this with LIKE condition.

Thanks for help everybody.

Answer (score 0):

you can use (.isSpace) to locate white spacing which separates each words , this is not exact answer , but you can start research from this way .

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "your string";
String[] separator = str.split(" ");//this will split string with space " "
String firstword = separator  [0]; // "your"
String secondword = separator [1]; // "string"
```

whatever you'' put in string.split will be used as divider,splitter